# What threading algorithm(s) does Python's IMAP library support?

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, imap

The [documentation for `IMAP4.thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.thread) in the `imaplib` library says

> The `thread` command is a variant of `search` with threading semantics for the results. Returned data contains a space separated list of thread members.
>
> Thread members consist of zero or more messages numbers, delimited by spaces, indicating successive parent and child.
>
> Thread has two arguments before the *search_criterion* argument(s); a *threading_algorithm*, and the searching *charset*.

It's not clear to me what to use for the *threading_algorithm* argument. The documentation doesn't indicate a default value, and the [source code for the `IMAP4.thread()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/imaplib.py#l836)

```
def thread(self, threading_algorithm, charset, *search_criteria):
        """IMAPrev1 extension THREAD command.

        (type, [data]) = <instance>.thread(threading_algorithm, charset, search_criteria, ...)
        """

        name = 'THREAD'
        typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, threading_algorithm, charset, *search_criteria)
        return self._untagged_response(typ, dat, name)
```

doesn't give me any ideas either, even after digging into the `_simple_command` helper function.

What should I use for this argument? Is there documentation elsewhere for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the server; the CAPABILITIES response should tell you what threading algorithms the server supports, under the THREAD= keys.

For example:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE AUTH=PLAIN ACL ACL2=UNION ID] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2011 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
```

This server supports the ORDEREDSUBJECT and REFERENCES algorithms.

The description of the baseline algorithms is indicated in the [IMAP SORT and THREAD RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256).

imaplib is a very low level library, you will need to parse the responses yourself.

Comment: Likely, you wish to use REFERENCES if the server supports it.

Comment: You can see the list of capabilities in the return value of `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL().login(username, password)` . Gmail doesn't seem to return this information.

Comment: Some servers will return capabilities unprompted, some you need to ask for it.

Comment: How do I ask for capabilities?

Comment: It seems not to be documented, but the IMAP4 classes support a capability() command: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/imaplib.py#L449